# How to convert an Observable stream into an Observable Array

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, observable

I am trying to retrieve a list of dogs from a database. I want to retrieve the list of dogs as an `Observable<Dog[]>`. However when I call toArray() or use any other method to try convert the incoming stream to an array I either receive no data when calling the `retrieveDogs(dogsId)` method. How does one go about retrieving an `Observable array` instead of just an `Observable stream`?

```
    retrieveDogs(dogIds : Array<string>): Observable<Dog[]>{
        return Observable.from(dogIds)
                .map(dogId => this.retrieveDog(dogId)) 
                .flatMap(dogObservable => dogObservable)
                .toArray();
     }

    retrieveDog(dogId : string) : Observable<DogEntity> {
     //afDB -> AngularFireDatabase that returns an observable with the data from the firebase database
        return this.afDB.object(DB_DOGS + DB_DASH + dogId)
                .map(dogObject =>DogEntity.convertObject(dogId,dogObject)
    }
```

Comment: short story, you don't, observables are streams of events. you can use toArray to buffer all the data from the src observable into an array. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md is that what you want?

Comment: I get what you mean about the streams. I noticed that toArray() requires some form of complete() method to have been fired in order for it to encapsulate the array and return the observable. The AngularFire methods unfortunately do not fire any complete methods therefore toArray() just sits waiting and therefore nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that to retrieve your data:

```
retrieveDogs(dogIds : Array<string>): Observable<Dog[]>{
  let obs = dogIds.map(dogId => this.retrieveDog(dogId));

  return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
}

retrieveDog(dogId : string) : Observable<DogEntity> {
  return this.afDB.object(DB_DOGS + DB_DASH + dogId)
    .map(dogObject => DogEntity.convertObject(dogId,dogObject));
}
```

Simple demo here http://jsbin.com/sotunopocu/2/edit?js,console